# No-break (IPS) circuit analysis and improvement

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis

I'm building a simple circuit that resembles a nobreak operation to power portable applications.

[image: No-Break circuit]

The working is simple: When a power supply (10-20V) V1 is connected it charges the 6V lead acid battery and provides power to the load (represented by R5). When power V1 is disconnected, the load gets power from B1.

R1 and R2 sets the output voltage of regulator to about 7.6V. Considering a voltage drop of 0.6V on D1, B1 gets 7V as its charging voltage.

D1 protects the regulator if V1 is disconnected.

Q1, R3 and R4 is a current limiting circuit. Using R4 = 1R gives about 600mA as current limit. When R4 is about 600mA, Q1 starts to conduct, dropping the voltage on the ADJ pin of U1 thereafter droping voltage on output pin of LM317, effectively limiting current flow.

Most of this circuit is based on the [LM317 Texas Instuments Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm317) reference circuit (page 11).

Everything works like expected. Output voltage, current limit, the battery gets charged and provides power to the load when V1 is disconnected.

I'd like to add some protection to the circuit but don't know how to do it.

**Question 1: How can I add a protection agains polarity reversal of B1?**

When I tested this situation I measured a 25mA current flowing through B1, and some of these gets through R1, R2 and some through the ADJ pin of LM. Is there a simple way to now allow current flow in this situation?

**Question 2: Do you have any recomendation to improve this circuit (besides replacing D1 to a Schottky type to get a lower voltage drop)?**

Comment: One improvement: Swap the collector and emitter on your transistor!

Comment: Oh crap. That't true. The schematics are wrong. Thank you @Dave.

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant, but you could put a diode right across your battery.  It would be reverse biased if the battery is inserted correctly, otherwise you would have a fuse or resettable polyfuse in series with the battery that would open when the battery is inserted backwards.

Other possibilities get more complicated or less efficient in normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

Improvement suggestion: See "battery charger IC" or similar for IC companies like Maxim and Linear Technologies. These chips take care of a number of issues including lower voltage drop. Even if you don't end up using one, the data sheets and application notes can inform your thinking.